# PNG in <img> tag in dark mode in Chrome

Tags: css, image, google-chrome, darkmode

For some reason Chrome is modifying my PNGs in dark mode and I cannot fix it in CSS...
I tried resetting the `filter`, but to no avail

```
        filter: brightness(1) contrast(1)  grayscale(1)  invert(1) saturate(1) hue-rotate(0);
```

Source: https://assets.tumblr.com/images/default_avatar/sphere_open_64.png#_=_

Light mode:

[image: Light mode]

Dark mode:

[image: Dark mode]

Any idea?

Comment: Are you sure the "dark" theme is not changing the png source with another img?. Can you show us a bit of the code?.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the  element for you image. Inside the element you can use  elements. These source elements can use a media query, like in CSS, to determine if it should show based on the query.

In your case you could check the prefers-color-scheme: dark query to see if dark mode is enabled.

If it is not enabled then the default src on the image is used.
If it is enabled then the srcset on the  element will be used as the new value for the src on the image.

```
<picture>
  <source srcset="dark-image.jpg" media="(prefers-color-scheme: dark)">
  <img src="light-image.jpg" alt="Animated wave shape">
</picture>
```

Answer (score 0):

try to add !important to your filter property.

```
filter: none !important;
```